# Hyperlinks are not visible in the generated PDF CV

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs, pdf

Don't know if it's intentional or not, but hyperlinks are colored like a normal text in the generated PDF on careers.stackoverflow.com, which makes them indistinguishable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. The CSS for the HTML used to generate the PDF contains this:

```
a, a:visited { color: inherit; text-decoration: none; }
```

This has the effect of making links the default colour, with no underline.

I would guess the intention is that a PDF is like a printed page, and you can't click links on paper. If you want an interactive version of your CV with clickable links, why not just share a link to your profile page instead of generating a PDF?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's because some companies (including Google) still want your CV to be uploaded in PDF format, no links accepted. I thought it would be useful to have the hyperlinks displayed correctly.

Comment: You certainly *can* click links in a PDF, though. It is not simply a static piece of paper. In fact, if you don't strip out the links before generating a PDF, this just makes for a landmine of possible click targets with no visual indication of their presence.